# $\Gamma$-equivalence definition of zero-cycles

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, schemes, arithmetic-geometry, algebraic-cycles

Let $\Gamma$ is a smooth projective curve, $x_1, x_2$ two distinc fixed points on
$\Gamma$, and $X$ a smooth projective variety.

In definition-Lemma 1  Roitman paper "On $\Gamma$-equivalence of $0$-dimensional cycles" says:

Two cycles  $A_1$ and $A_2$ in $Z_0(X)$ are $(\Gamma, x_1,x_2)$-equivalents, denoted by $A_1\sim_{\Gamma} A_2$,  if there exists a one dimensional cycle $T$ on $\Gamma\times X$ such that
\begin{equation*}
    i^*_{x_1}(T)=A_1, \text{ and } i^*_{x_2}(T)=A_2, 
\end{equation*}
where

\begin{array}{cccc}
  i_{y}:& X &\rightarrow & \Gamma\times X  \\
         & x &\mapsto & y\times x
\end{array}

Well, this definition is not  clear for me yet because I think that in the above definition, $i^*_{y}$ is the pull-back of $i_y$, i.e., $i^*_{y}:Z_1(\Gamma\times X)\rightarrow Z_0(X)$, so it means  that $i_y$ is flat of relative dimension $-1$ (because, as far as I know, we should need these two properties to define the pull-back).  Can the relative dimension of a morphism be negative? If not,  How can I justify the existence of $i^*_{y}$?

Comment: I think you want the displayed morphism to be $i_y:X \to \Gamma \times X$ (without the star), so then $i_y^*$ is the pullback map on $0$-cycles.

Comment: I think the way you want to think about $i_y$ is as an isomorphism onto its image, the constant section $\left\{y\right\}\times X$. The factored version is therefore of relative dimension $0$. The point is just that $T$ intersects the section in a finite set a.k.a. the support of a $0$-cycle.

Comment: You don't need to define a whole morphism $Z_1(\Gamma\times X)\to Z_0(X)$ to pull back this one cycle: $T$ is assumed to pull back correctly, and that should be the end of that. This is exactly what happens with rational equivalence, which is what this is generalizing. (One sign you're barking up the wrong tree is that there's no such thing as a morphism of schemes with relative dimension $-1$, nor is $X\to \Gamma\times X$ flat, because it isn't open.)

Comment: @TabesBridges Thank you!. I already edited and fixed the error in the question.

Comment: Thank you @KReiser!!!!!